# Space Situational Awareness: What Key Issues were identified (in an Evolving Landscape)?

Tags: law, regulatory, international-politics, government, united-states

The recent House Science, Space, and Technology Committee Hearing: [Space Situational Awareness: Key Issues in an Evolving Landscape](https://science.house.gov/hearings/space-situational-awareness-key-issues-in-an-evolving-landscape) lasted about 90 minutes, the video is included below and there are transcripts of each witnesses testimony and credentials in the link above.

**Question:** What would a summary of this hearing be; what were the key issues identified in this hearing? Could it be summarized by Professor Joanne Gabrynowicz, Professor Emerita of Space Law, University of Mississippi Law Center's "[Space is not lawless. But the law is unclear.](https://science.house.gov/imo/media/doc/Oltrogge%20Testimony.pdf)" or were some more specific and concrete points identified where new law is needed?

**in response to comments:**  Though I am [not a CSPAN fan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53579814#53579814) I have indeed watched most of the video and skimmed through the transcripts, ergo the quote from Professor Gabrynowicz. I don't recommend watching it. I came away believing that no key issues were identified, but I am hoping that people knowledgable in the field will have more familiarity with the situation and be able add more context, the transcripts I've linked to may offer some clues.

Comment: So do you just not have time to watch the video, or...?

Comment: @Chris Though I am [not a CSPAN fan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53579814#53579814) I have indeed watched most of the video and skimmed through the transcripts. I don't recommend it. I came away believing that no key issues were identified, but I am hoping that people knowledgable in the field will have more familiarity with the situation and be able add more context. btw did you down vote before waiting for my reply to your helpful comment?

Comment: In general, law/authority only extends as far as enforcement. Since currently there are no space marines or space police, countries can only really govern and make laws about launching things from their soil.

Comment: @Dragongeek I like the sound of "Space Marines" much better than *[SpaceForce!](https://youtu.be/_AUXpnB065o)*